# Adding Jquery UI to UL in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to be able to add jquery UI to the list on **GoalNotes**  This table gets populated by what the user enters in the "name1" and "data1" input fields. Every time I give the  an id, the program breaks and I get no errors. Any ideas on how I could apply animations to the table rows that get added after the user inputs data?

**html**

```
<section class="section section--active color1" data-letter="M">
  <article class="section__wrapper">
    <h1 class="section__title">Monday</h1>
    <div id="Monday" class="tabcontent">
      <form name="goalsList1" action = "/created" method="POST">
        <div id="tab1">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td><b>New Goal:</b><input type="text" name="name1" id="name1"></td>
              <td><b>Notes:</b><input type="text" name="data1" id="data1"></td>
              <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Save"  onclick="SaveItem(1)"> 
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div id="items_table1">
          <h2>List of goals</h2>
          <table id="list1" contenteditable> </table>
          <p>
            <label><input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="ClearAll(1)"></label>
          </p>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```

**javascript**

```js
function doShowAll(numOfWeek) {
  if (CheckBrowser()) {
    var key = "";
    var list = "**<tr><th>Goal</th><th>Notes</th></tr>**\n";
    var i = 0;
    var goals = localStorage[numOfWeek] ? JSON.parse(localStorage[numOfWeek]) : {};
    var goalsKeys = Object.keys(goals);
    for (i = 0; i < goalsKeys.length; i++) {
      key = goalsKeys[i];
      list += "<tr><td>" + key + "</td>\n<td>"
      + goals[key] + "</td></tr>\n";
    }
    if (list == "<tr><th>Goal</th><th>Notes</th></tr>\n") {
      list += "<tr><td><i>nothin' here</i></td>\n<td><i>nothin' here either</i></td></tr>\n";
    }
    document.getElementById('list'+numOfWeek).innerHTML = list;

  } else {
    alert('Cannot store list as your browser do not support local storage');
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('#due-date').datepicker();
  $('#add-todo').button({
    icons: {
      primary: "ui-icon-circle-plus"
    }
  }).click(function() {
    $('#new-todo').dialog('open');
  }); // end click
  $('#new-todo').dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    close: function() {
      $('#new-todo input').val(''); /*clear fields*/
    },
    buttons : {
      "Add task" : function() {
        var taskName = $('#task').val();
        var dueDate = $('#due-date').val();
        var beginLi = '<li><span class="done">%</span><span class="delete">x</span>';
        var taskLi = '<span class="task">' +   taskName + '</span>';
        var dateLi = '<span class="due-date">' +   dueDate + '</span>';
        var endLi = '</li>';
        $('#todo-list').prepend(beginLi + taskLi + dateLi + endLi);
        $('#todo-list').hide().slideDown(250).find('li:first')
        .animate({
          'background-color': '#ff99c2'
        },250)
        .animate({
          'background-color': '#d9b3ff'
        },250).animate; // end animate
        $(this).dialog('close');
      },
      "Cancel" : function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
      }
    }
  }); 

  $('#todo-list').on('click','.done',function(e) {
    var $taskItem = $(this).parent("li");
    var $copy = $taskItem.clone();
    $('#completed-list').prepend($copy);
    $copy.hide().slideDown(); 
    $taskItem.remove();
  }
                    ); // end on

  $('#todo-list, #completed-list').on('click','.delete',function(e) {
    $(this).parent("li").slideUp(250, function() {
      $(this).remove();
    }); // end slideup
  }); // end on

  $('#todo-list').sortable();

}); // end ready
```

http://jsbin.com/digefufeca/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: **jquery-ui is a library not a specific plugin**. Which widget of jquery-ui are you trying to use? Can you create a snippet or bin for this?

Comment: I want to add these jqueryui widgets: datepicker, button and  dialog.  For animations, I want to use slideDown and slideUp. I also want to use prepend, hide, find and remove. I'm trying to do something similar to what it's shown on 45:36 on this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rra6Mh4IGSY

Comment: OK. again.. can you create a **working** [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or [bin](http://jsbin.com/) with you code so we could see what you achive so far?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/digefufeca/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem**

The `form` with nane `goalsList1` is sending whenever you click on the button.

Why? because the button is `submit` button.

**The solution(s)**

1. Replace the button's type to `button`. ([link](http://jsbin.com/batina/2/edit?html,css,js))
2. Prevent the form submission by `event.preventDefault()`. ([link](http://jsbin.com/batina/4/edit?html,css,js))

There are more ways but those are the major.

**Note:** your code still not working but now you can see the error message.